# How to correctly override systemd scripts

Tags: systemd

I want to apply a patch to `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia`. Namely, I want to apply the patch shown in [this comment](https://github.com/pop-os/systemd/issues/15#issuecomment-1153401200).

I can do it, but as soon as some system update overrides it, I lose the patch.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: That comment isn't a patch, it's a full script.  If that file is owned by a package, it will be over-written when the package is updated.  You could add your own script as its own file, or undo nvidia's actions.  This new file would probably be safe from packages.  See `man systemd-sleep` for details.  Especially the part that says "scripts or binaries dropped in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ are intended for local use only and should be considered hacks".  Your nvidia file doesn't seem to be local (managed by package maintainer) so it's definately a problem that it gets overwritten.

Comment: I could override the systemd units that use the nvidia script. But how can I find them? I tried with `grep -r /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia` but found nothing

Comment: See `man systemd-sleep`.  The units that run these are `systemd-suspend.service` and the `hibernate`/`hybrid-sleep`/`suspend-then-sleep` equivalents.  They call `systemd-sleep suspend` (or equivalent) and *that* will execute everything in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`.

Comment: Thanks, so I assume there's no solution to this question. I need another approach (e.g. custom post-update hooks)

Answer (score 0):

According to info given in the comments, there's no method provided by systemd itself. However, it is solvable using hooks in the package manager: you should hook installations and upgrades of the package that provides the `nvidia` scripts. The details depend on the specific Linux distro.